# On centOS is Impossible to access to phpPgAdmin due to pgsql not found

Tags: php, postgresql, centos, phppgadmin, php-pgsql

CWP Pro version 7
PHP 7.4
PHP built with modules pdo_pgsql and pgsql
PostgreSQL version 9.2.24

PostgreSQL started from the CWP, the database created and user linked. but trying to access to link https://93.188.164.66:2031/phpPgAdmin/ (from CWP menu) the page is blank with the message:
`Your PHP installation does not support PostgreSQL. You need to recompile PHP using the --with-pgsql configuration option.`

into the PHP info tab the configure command is:

```
'./configure' '--with-config-file-path=/usr/local/php' '--enable-cgi' '--with-config-file-scan-dir=/usr/local/php/php.d' '--with-zlib=/usr' '--enable-mbstring' '--with-zip' '--enable-bcmath' '--enable-pcntl' '--enable-ftp' '--enable-exif' '--enable-calendar' '--enable-sysvmsg' '--enable-sysvsem' '--enable-sysvshm' '--with-tidy' '--with-curl' '--with-iconv' '--with-gmp' '--with-pspell' '--enable-gd' '--with-jpeg' '--with-freetype' '--enable-gd-jis-conv' '--with-webp' '--with-zlib-dir=/usr' '--with-xpm' '--with-openssl' '--with-gettext=/usr' '--with-bz2=/usr' '--enable-soap' '--enable-phar' '--with-xsl' '--with-xmlrpc' '--with-kerberos' '--enable-posix' '--enable-sockets' '--with-external-pcre' '--with-libdir=lib64' '--with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' '--enable-intl' '--with-imap' '--with-imap-ssl' '--enable-litespeed' '--with-pgsql=/usr/lib64/pgsql' '--with-pdo-pgsql' '--with-password-argon2' 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig'
```

and into the php.ini:

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

are not commented.

Why can't the server see the proper pgsql stuff and phpPgAdmin is not accessible?

Comment: Have no idea about the PHP issues, just a heads up that Postgresql  9.2 is coming up on 5 years past EOL. In other words there is no community support for it and there have been no security/bug fixes applied in years.

Comment: Should I update PostgreSQL in your opinion so?

Comment: Yes. Look at [Versioning](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) for the life span of currently supported versions(10-14).

Comment: checking under yum packages I can see that I have both Postgres 9.2 and 13 installed. how can I switch from one to another? and should it fix the issue with phpPgAdmin?

Comment: I use `psql` for interacting with Postgres so I don't deal with GUI interfaces like `phpPgAdmin`. That being said I don't see changing Postgres version helping with the issue as that seems to be coming from the `PHP` side. Probably the simplest way to upgrade is to use the 13 version of `pg_dump` to dump the 9.2 database and then use the 13 version of `pg_restore` to create the database in the 13 instance.